# what is the http status code returned by the server

Tags: http

When the password entered by the client is wrong, what is the http status code returned by the server? 401 or 200? Thank you. i have responsed to client 403,they said 403 is wrong,then the 200 is right

Comment: Definitely not 200 if the password is wrong. Look up HttpStatusCodes.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status codes are typically set by code running on the server, or are determined by configuration of the web server, so the answer to your question is implementation-dependent.

That being said, I believe you are asking about the *conventional use* of these codes. Again, it depends what kind of application

- For a web service that requires authentication, it is normal to return 403 (and no body) for an unauthorized request.
- For a web site that that requires a static form of authentication, such as client certificates or AD identity, 403 is also pretty common.
- For a web site that requires a signon, and has its own signon page, it is normal to return a 200, accompanied by a body containing HTML that allows the user to try again.

Comment: I'd argue that for the first two cases, 401 is way more conventional than 403. It's also in line with the [spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Answer (score 0):

It returns **401 (Unauthorized)** status code.

> > The 401 (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has not
> >        been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for
> >        the target resource.